# am building the facebook gif post project, when i click on the gif it has to dispaly in the text area. But am stuck with type error post.map is nt fun

Tags: java, reactjs, api

this is my main code, when I click on any gif am getting the data that is stored in the state but when I try to display the data in UI, am getting this below error.
[image]

`import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from 'axios';
import "./componentsStyles/GifContainerStyles.css"
import GifInText from './GifInText';

```
const GifPost = ({open, onClose}) => {
  const [gifs, setGifs] = useState([])
  const [gifId, setGifId] = useState([ ])
   
   console.log("gifs:",gifs )
  
  const fetchData = async () =>{
    const response = await axios
    .get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending",{
        params: {
            api_key: "Xoa3mXrWxKXw6lJscrKUTsbZsXLbGuGY"
        }
    }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log("error at fetching data", error);
      });
      setGifs(response.data)
    };           
const getGifId = (id) => {
    setGifId(id);
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchData()
     
}, [ ]);
      return (
            <>
                </div>
                   <div className='post-text'>
                   <form><textarea placeholder='Whats on your mind?'></textarea> </form> 
                     {Object.keys(gifId).length === 0 ?  null : <GifInText  gifId={gifId}/> }
                 </div>
                 <div className='gif-container'>
                        <>
                            {Object.keys(gifs).length === 0 ? (<div>loading...</div>):
                                <div className='gif-section'>
                                    {
                                        gifs.data.map((items)=>{
                                            return(
                                                <a href="#" className='image-gifs' key= 
                                                                {items.id}>
                                                    <img className="live-gifs" onClick= 
             {()=>getGifId(items.id)} src={items.images.fixed_height.url} alt="..."/>
                                                </a>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            }
                        </>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
               }
               export default GifPost;`
```

this is child component

`import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios"
const GifInText = ({gifId}) => {
console.log("id:",gifId);

```
    const [post, setPost] = useState([])
    console.log("post:",post );

    const fetchData = async () =>{
           axios.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/${gifId}`,{
                params: { 
                    api_key: "Xoa3mXrWxKXw6lJscrKUTsbZsXLbGuGY",
                    gif_id: gifId
                }
            }).catch((error) =>{console.log("error at fetching gifID2", error);
                }).then(response => {setPost(response.data) });}

        useEffect(()=>{
          fetchData()
        }, [fetchData])
        
        return (
            <div>         
                {
                    post.data && post.data.map((items)=>{
                        return(
                            <a href="#" className='image-gifs' key={items.id}>
                                <img className="live-gifs" src={items.data.images} alt="..."/>
                            </a>
                        )
                    })
                }           
            </div> 
         )
}
export default GifInText;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use map function on an `object`. You can only use `map` function directly on `arrays`.
In your console log, `post` is an object that contains more objects like `data` and `meta`.

Therefore, you need to make the following changes:

Firstly, change the `state`

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({});
```

And finally, use `map` on an object like this:

```
Object.values(post.data).length && Object.values(post.data).map((item)=>{
    //use item here
})
```

Comment: sorry mate it's giving me an error again but this time am not getting the data when I clicked on gif.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)

Comment: Made an edit. You can test it again. Basically my check for empty object wasn't correct that's why the part after 'and' statement was getting triggered. @user17714857